# Print content and exit if the content can fit in one screen in less command

Tags: less

I have the following in my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
pager = less -+$LESS -MR
```

This makes `less` to be used for `git` commands. `git` commands output contents in `less` irrespective of the size of the content. After I hit <kbd>q</kbd>, the whole content disappears, and I return to my clean bash prompt.

If I remove `-+$LESS`, it quits when I hit <kbd>q</kbd> or if the whole content can fit in one screen after printing it out. That is my bash prompt is not clear, it has previously shown output of the `less` command.

I can get the above behavior just by removing `-+$LESS` but I can't do it in normal bash prompt.

How can I get the behavior specified in the paragraph with `-+$LESS` inside normal bash commands and not only `git` commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man less`:

```
-F or --quit-if-one-screen
       Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.
```

Adding `-F` to the `$LESS` environment variable should do the trick.

```
[core]
pager = less -+$LESS -MRF
```